# is it impossible to use CUDA in ROS with updating opencv to opencv 2.4.3?

Tags: ros, slam, rgbd-slam, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everybody, first of all, I would like to modify RGBDSLAM source, can i?Then, I want to use opencv2.4.3, GPU CUDA implementations with the ORB to take the place of SIFTGPU. is it Feasible? and i Would like to ask you how to  upgrade opencv ?Is there some good advice?  and my pc:ubuntu 11.10 64bit.ROS   Fuerte. thanks a lot . and if you have the usefull message ,you can send email to goujiaolong@gmail.com

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59056/is-it-impossible-to-use-cuda-in-ros-with-updating-opencv-to-opencv-2.4.3?/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-03-24

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-03-27**:
but i donot know how to update opencv to opencv2.4.3 with cuda. can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure you can modify it. Feel free to share your changes.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-04-24**:
but i donot know how to update opencv to opencv2.4.3 with cuda. can you give me some advice?

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-04-24**:
additional, if i want to use other Matching algorithm,Which I should change? thanks.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-04-25**:
Feature Matching is done in src/node.cpp method featureMatching(...).